# Best way to provisionning CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, vmware-vcenter, foreman, provisioning

I began my new work, it's in a small infrastructure but they often provisionning new virtual machines under CentOS.
Currently they used template in VMWare VCenter but it's just a clone and when they want to modify the clone they have to provision it and then create a new template from this new VM.

I transform all the packages intallation and configuration into ansible roles but I continue to use VMWare template...

Do you know a product that you can link with VMWare infrastructure and provision CentOS VM from scratch ?

Thank you for advance, Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I used classic PXE provided by Foreman which callback ansible roles after the provisioning

Answer (score 0):

Terraform and Ansible work well together for this exact scenario.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but with Terraform you can not pass a kickstart or a partition table ? Can Terraform call a ansible playbook once its job is done ?